# Find out the Kind for an ID in appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Given a datastore id, is there a way to find out the Kind of the object for that ID. Or am I wrong in assuming that ids in app engine is unique regardless of the Kind? I am using the low-level api on Java.

Thanks
Klas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs are only unique for a given kind and parent entity, not globally, so there's no way to get an entity given only the ID. If you don't know the kind, you need to transmit the encoded entity key, rather than just the ID.

Comment: Thanks, really good to know. I will revisit my coding based on this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, your assumption is valid, ID provided by the datastore seems to be unique regardless of the Kind.

EDIT:
Sorry, I was wrong. Apparently, as Nick had confirmed on the comment, IDs are guaranteed to be unique only for the same Kind and my observation only applies to entities in the development server.

However, I'm afraid at the moment the only way to know what Kind is associated with a certain ID is to load the entity from the datastore and check the getKind() value.

Comment: Thanks, but I find no way to load the entity without knowing the Kind. The KeyFactory requires both Kind and Id to generate a Key. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ah yes, it's becoming a catch-22 then. Well, the only thing come into my mind is using `DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService().getIndexes()` to get all the indexes on your app, use `getKind()` from each of the Index and construct a set of Kinds, and try to load the entity by using the set of Kinds until you get the one that returns a result. (ugly workaround, I know)

Comment: Yes, that would be a workaround, but quite ineffective. In our problem, the Kind kan be one of four or five known kinds, so we could try with iterating those, but even this will lead to overhead. I was hoping for having overlooked some documentation, but it might be so that there is no way of doing this.

Comment: It appears so, might you consider storing the entity with your own provided key string rather than asking the datastore to generate it for you? You can encode the Kind on the key as a prefix then, and you could append it with unique string generated by java.util.UUID to ensure the key's uniqueness. And if my answer is valid for your question, might you kindly accept the answer?

Comment: This is not the case. IDs are only guaranteed unique for a given kind and parent entity. The fact that they're globally unique in the dev_appserver (only!) is an accident of implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Nick! Upvoted your answer to replace mine.

Comment: Thanks Nick, that really takes my question away and explains things.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an entity key, you can get the kind using [getKind](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity?csw=1#getKind%28%29) (they kind is actually part of the decoded key).

But you need the Kind in order to construct a full key from an id using [KeyFactory.createKey](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory?csw=1#createKey%28java.lang.String,%20long%29).